# What exactly is the executable produced by Opa?

Tags: deployment, opa

Is it a server? Or do I need to run Opa behind apache? Basically - if I want to deploy an Opa application, would it be as simple as launching the executable on a VPS for example, or would I need some other stack elements?

EDIT: Noticed a similar question, but I am interested in whether or not I can deploy using JUST the exe - not behind any server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Opa compiler produces a standalone executable. You don't need any other stack elements, the web server is fully integrated into the produced executable.

The only elements that you can launch it's an external database. 
But you can use Opa database (DB3) as local which doesn't need a db server (`./monapp.exe --db-local /path/to/db`, if option `--db-local` is not set a default path is used).

If you want a Mongo database, the application should be compiled with the `--database mongo` options. The produced executable will be able to auto-install MongoDb (`./monapp.exe --db-local /path/to/mongodb`)